# how to provide guided tour (tooltip tour) for a Windows application in C#

Tags: c#, tooltip

I am looking for a way to improve the existing tour of our application. I have seen googlemap's latest "MapsGL!" tour and want to implement something like that for our application which is  written in C#.

The use case is to show our customer a series of tooltips near the appropriate controls which should be clicked in order to complete the workflow.

Is there anyway we can do this in C#?

[EDIT]

The application I am talking about is a WINDOWS APPLICATION not a WEB APPLICATION

Comment: Yes there is, but this kind of question is ill fitting for a QA website. Instead you should provide some code to show what you have tried so far, and what seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello try with Tooltip property

<asp:webcontrol id="id" ToolTip="string" runat="server" />

For example button

<form runat="server">
<asp:Button id="button1" Text="Submit" runat="server"
ToolTip="This is an example-button" />
</form>
```